# Receiving two different, random elements of a list without deleting | Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, random

I got a list `List<String> name = ['Max', 'Easter', 'Egg'];`
and want to generate two random numbers to get a random String of the List.

```
var rnd = new Random();
int player1;
int player2;

void rndnbrs() {
setState(() {
    player1 = rnd.nextInt(name.length);
    player2 = rnd.nextInt(name.length);
 }
}
```

So, now I can use `name[player1] and name[player2] in Text()`

I want player1 and player2 to be different numbers.

Thought about deleting element `name.removeAt(player1)` after generating player1, and adding it right after generating player2 back to the List, but that's not possible (would be a waste of time for you, so I won´t explain why).

You guys got any ideas? I´m new to flutter, so there may be a simple solution that I just don't know about :)

Comment: Use [`List.shuffle`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/List/shuffle.html) and select two elements from the shuffled list.

Comment: didn´t knew about this one, thanks for your answer!

Comment: @jamesdlin : If your comment answered the question, post it as such.  Especially to keep this site from seeing this question as unanswered.